# Why does my deja dup restore run out of space?

Tags: deja-dup

I back up my "Home (myname)" folder weekly using Deja Dup to an external hard drive. The external HD is 320 GB. My computer is 160GB, with

Partition 1=WinRE 13GB (sda1)
Partition 2=Win7 52GB (sda2)
Extended Partion 3=Ubuntu 89GB (sda3)
Free = 6GB (sda4)
:EP3(sda3) has 3 partitions: sda5 (swap 2GB), sda6(Data 61GB), sda7(Filesystem 26GB)

After a crash I tried to restore using Deja Dup, but the restore was only partial because I got a free space warning. When I looked at what happened I found that my "/home" folder was full (only 200MB left), and the partition (sda7) was also full.

Since I only backed up the "Home (myname)" folder, and I ticked 'Restore to original location' when doing the restore

a) how can the restore be bigger than than where it came from?
b) why has this happened?
c) what can I do to untangle the situation?

Comment: you better run bootinfoscript to describe your partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Deja Dup retains older backups, so you can restore from a long time ago. This means that on your drive there are several copies of the backups. If you only use it for backups then fine. Deja Dup will automatically delete older ones once it gets full. Otherwise open up Deja-Dup and click the schedule tab in settings, and set it to only keep backups for a week. Then clear the drive and run a manual backup.

Comment: The problem is not with the backup. The external drive has plenty of space. The problem is that when I choose to RESTORE the latest backup (from last Thursday), I get a file space error message and the restore aborts i.e. the space problem is on my computer! The message says that "/" has only 200MB, and when I dig further it seems to be the /home directory which is now filling partition sda7 (Filesystem). But how on earth can my computer have run out of storage space when I was only restoring what was there on Thursday, back to the same location, and I have not done anything since then???!!!!